# What are the relationships between package commands?

Tags: yum, rpm, zypper

RPM based package managers support subcommands such as requires, recommends, conflicts, obsoletes, suggests and supplements.

In reading the rpm man pages and dependencies documentation, it isn't clear how these differ.

For example, if i run the command `rpm --query --info MozillaFirefox`, the following output is returned.

```
Name        : MozillaFirefox
Version     : 60.4.0
Release     : lp150.3.30.1
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Sun 06 Jan 2019 07:43:50 AM NZDT
Group       : Productivity/Networking/Web/Browsers
Size        : 161608776
License     : MPL-2.0
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Thu 13 Dec 2018 08:35:09 PM NZDT, Key ID b88b2fd43dbdc284
Source RPM  : MozillaFirefox-60.4.0-lp150.3.30.1.src.rpm
Build Date  : Wed 12 Dec 2018 10:35:10 PM NZDT
Build Host  : cloud138
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : http://bugs.opensuse.org
Vendor      : openSUSE
URL         : http://www.mozilla.org/
Summary     : Mozilla Firefox Web Browser
Description :
Mozilla Firefox is a standalone web browser, designed for standards
compliance and performance.  Its functionality can be enhanced via a
plethora of extensions.
```

If i run the command `rpm --query --recommends MozillaFirefox`, the following output is returned.

```
libavcodec-full >= 0.10.16
libcanberra0
libpulse0
```

I assume that libpulse0 refers to the PulseAudio package. If yes, the command `rpm --query --info pulseaudio` returns

```
Name        : pulseaudio
Version     : 11.1
Release     : lp150.4.1
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Sun 06 Jan 2019 06:49:12 AM NZDT
Group       : System/Sound Daemons
Size        : 3605819
License     : GPL-2.0+ AND LGPL-2.1+
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Mon 23 Apr 2018 10:39:20 AM NZST, Key ID b88b2fd43dbdc284
Source RPM  : pulseaudio-11.1-lp150.4.1.src.rpm
Build Date  : Mon 23 Apr 2018 10:38:51 AM NZST
Build Host  : build70
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : https://bugs.opensuse.org
Vendor      : openSUSE
URL         : http://pulseaudio.org
Summary     : A Networked Sound Server
Description :
pulseaudio is a networked sound server for Linux, other Unix like
operating systems and Microsoft Windows. It is intended to be an
improved drop-in replacement for the Enlightened Sound Daemon (ESOUND).
```

If the `pulseaudio` package is already installed, why is there a recommendation to install `libpulse0`?

- What do recommends, conflicts, obsoletes, suggests and supplements
  refer to?
- What is the difference between recommends, suggests and supplements?
- When should they be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rpm --query --recommends MozillaFirefox
```

lists the packages which the `MozillaFirefox` package recommends (I’ll explain that further down). As with most things interpreted by a computer, the output is to be taken literally; so the `libpulse0` recommendation concerns the `libpulse0` package, not the `pulseaudio` package.

The list of packages is static, and shown as defined in the `MozillaFirefox` package; it doesn’t take into account packages which are already installed on your system.

The package relationships are as follows:

- requires: package A requires on package B if it needs package B to function;
- recommends: package A recommends package B if it can use package B, and most users would use the two packages together (this is known as a weak dependency);
- suggests: package A suggests package B if it can use package B, but most users wouldn’t need it (this is known as a very weak dependency);
- supplements: package A supplements package B if it adds functionality to package B, and most users would use the two packages together (it’s pretty much symmetric with “recommends”);
- enhances: package A enhances package B if it adds functionality to package B, but most users wouldn’t find it particularly useful (it’s pretty much symmetric with “suggests”).

This should help you understand what these terms refer to, what the differences between them are, and when they should be used.

Whether the relationships are actually taken into account depends on the package management tool being used. `rpm` itself deals with individual packages, so only strong dependencies matter to it (“requires”). As far as I’m aware, `yum` also only takes strong dependencies into account. `dnf` is configured to install weak dependencies by default; see the `install_weak_deps` flag in `dnf.conf`. Zypper and `urpm` can also be configured to consider weak dependencies.

One added subtlety is the difference between the recommends/suggests and supplements/enhances pair, *i.e.* why we need both. They represent knowledge which is available in different places. For example, a package which can optionally use a library “knows” that it can do so; the appropriate relationship then is “recommends” or “suggests”. However, a package such as Firefox can’t possibly know all its plugins, so it doesn’t attempt to list all available plugins in “recommends” or “suggests”; each individual plugin can indicate that it adds functionality to Firefox by indicating that it “supplements” or “enhances” it in its RPM specification.

See [the RPM documentation](http://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and that's clearer. A couple of clarifications. At what point does recommends, suggests, supplements and enhance occur? For example, are these provided at the point of installation or is it an explicit query that a user has to run e.g. `rpm --query --recommends MozillaFirefox`. Secondly, what does "each individual plugin indicates that it adds functionality" mean? How does a plugin indicate?

Comment: Additionally, what is the relationship with `provides`?

Comment: See the update regarding the questions in your first comment. `provides` in the RPM world are quite complex, that should really be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional context. If `zypper`, `urpm` and `dnf` can be configured to consider weak dependencies, it would suggest that they are not be default. If yes, does that mean that if i wanted to consider `--recommends` for example, i would have to either configure the package manager or alternatively run commands such as `zypper info --recommends MozillaFirefox`. Would that be correct? Additionally, is there any benefit to configuring package manager to consider weak dependencies or is it simply a case of user preference?

Comment: As I mentioned in my update, `dnf` *is* configured to consider weak dependencies by default. I don’t know what the defaults for Zypper and `urpmi` are.

Comment: The RPM-based distributions I’m familiar with don’t use weak dependencies much, but Debian does, and that gives an indication of the benefit. By default, in Debian, hard dependencies and recommended dependencies are installed, and suggested dependencies are ignored. Users can configure their package manager to ignore recommended dependencies, for example if they want a smaller system. Ultimately as you say it’s mostly a case of user preference (since weak dependencies can always be overridden one way or another).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. It's far more easier to understand the relationships now. Yes, i noticed that you had mentioned `dnf` is configured to consider weak dependencies. Apologies for the oversight.